# Flow to reassign case if owner isn´t user not working

Tags: visual-workflow, automation, email2case

I have an easy task which I can´t get my head around. I have a flow which updates a case created from an email (Email-to-case). The owner (reassigned to a product queue from the Inbox) and a specific field gets automatically updated.

Now the agent takes over the ownership of the case.

When the agent answer to the client and the client wrotes back the flow reassigns the case to the queue. But it should stay with the previous owner.
How can I realise that?

[image]
[image]
[image]

KR Alex